# Force Particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, forces, carrier-particles, quantum-gravity

1. Since Einstein has shown that gravitational force is created by the warping of Space-Time, why are physicists looking for the "graviton" particle?
2. Since gravitational force is created by a warping of Space-Time, isn't it logical for electric & magnetic forces to be also created by warping Space-Time? Perhaps in a different dimension(s)?

Comment: the graviton corresponds to ripples in space-time

Comment: I am not aware of any physicists looking for gravitons. There is no technology today that could detect them. We can just barely detect gravitational waves consisting of vast numbers of gravitons. We have no hope of detecting individual gravitons any time soon.

Comment: Tip: Please ask unrelated subquestions in separate posts.

Comment: Your question #2 relates to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza-Klein_theory

Answer (score 1):

The fact is not that you just see that gravity warps spacetime, but that if you include into the dynamics of your theory space-time deformations, you get gravity as a result.

Electromagnetism comes from another kind of deformation: you can say they arise through the "deformation" of the (local, pointwise) definition of electric charge.

The idea is that nature is invariant with respect to a certain symmetry (here for instance something similar to swapping the sign of all the charges) and you can even extend this symmetry to be local (i.e. you do a transformation which depends on the space-time coordinate of each point). Going in more detail at this level seems inappropriate. You can have a look to this page if you feel like reading some more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory#Description .

In the case of gravity the starting-point symmetry is something similar to changes of reference frames.

These settings in which a different symmetry transformation can be done at each point are called gauge theories.